# JasperException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have two Data Model : User and Car, User can have many cars , so this is the User Class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="APP_USER")
public class User implements Serializable{

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;
......

@OneToMany(mappedBy="user",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Car> cars = new HashSet<Car>();
```

### Car.java :

```
@Entity
public class Car implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id ;
.....

@ManyToOne(optional=false)
@JoinColumn(name="user_fk")
private User user;
```

In the carController , I have the method to add a new Car for one user :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/cars")
public class CarController {

@Autowired
CarService carService;

@Autowired
UserService userService;

@RequestMapping(value={"/list"},method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String listCars(ModelMap model){
List<Car> cars = carService.allCars();
model.addAttribute("cars", cars);
return "car"; }

@ModelAttribute("utilisateurs")
public List<User> allUsers(){
List<User> utilisateurs = userService.findAllUsers();
return utilisateurs;
}  


@RequestMapping(value={"/newCar"},method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String newCar(ModelMap model){

Car car = new Car();
model.addAttribute("car",car);
return "carRegistration";
}

@RequestMapping(value={"newCar"},method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String newCar(@Valid Car car, BindingResult result,ModelMap model){

if (result.hasErrors()) {
    return "registration";
}
carService.save(car);
model.addAttribute("car",car);

return "redirect:/cars/list";
}
```

Finally , in the view , the form is :

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="car"
                            class="form-horizontal">

      <form:input type="hidden" path="id" id="id" />

      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Libelle</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <form:input type="text" path="libelle" id="libelle" style="height:4%" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Registration</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <form:input type="text" path="registration" id="email" />
        </div>
      </div>



      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Utilisateur</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <form:select path="user" items="${utilisateurs}"  itemValue="id" itemLabel="lastName" style="margin-left: 4%;"></form:select>
        </div>
      </div>   

      <div class="form-actions">
        <input type="submit" value="Validate" class="btn btn-success" />
      </div>

    </form:form>
```

I can get the view , but when I click on button submit , I get this error :

```
Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute.
```

I think there is a problem with the select item of users !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you provided any Spring converter or formatter for User ?

### applicationContext.xml:

```
 <bean id="conversionService"
      class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
        <list>
            <bean class="my.project.StringToUser"/>
            <bean class="my.project.StringToRole"/>

        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService" />
```

It will convert User id to User object.

### my.project.StringToUser:

```
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;

public class StringToUser implements Converter<String, JUser> {

  @Autowired
  private UserService userService;

  @Override
  public JUser convert(String source) {
      long id = Long.valueOf(source);
      return userService.get(id);
  }
}
```

the error :

```
WARNING: Failed to bind request element: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: 
    Failed to convert value of type [com.websystique.springmvc.model.User] to required type [com.websystique.springmvc.model.User]; 
nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException:
  Failed to convert from type [com.websystique.springmvc.model.User] to
  type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute @javax.validation.Valid com.websystique.springmvc.model.User] 
  for value 'User [id=null, ssoId=alaa, password=alaa1991, firstName=, lastName=, email=, userProfiles=null, accounts=null, userDocuments=[], cars=[], documents=[]]';
nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: 
   com.websystique.springmvc.model.User cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Comment: Thank you, this works for me .But I'm getting another error ,when adding w new user ( User view form )  , the error is : nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.websystique.springmvc.model.User cannot be cast to java.lang.String !!

Comment: May I have the method creating new user? I guess there is a problem in controller method arguments.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/alaa-bourouissi/4ce175f19f57a35131f82327cd80a4f4 , you can find User.java and AppController.java , this method is from a tutorial , so I'm not the writer of this code , it works fine before I write StringToUser.java class

Comment: Please expose full stack trace of the exception in question tail. Complete the question text.

Comment: Thank you Dariush Jafari , I just edited the post with the error

Comment: you can find user registration and car registration : https://gist.github.com/alaa-bourouissi/6a8652db42355dabb66ba3c46988d21b

Comment: I guess  `userProfiles` select control in userRegistration.jsp page is the problem point. How do you convert `UserProfile.id` (String) to UserProfile Object? Do you have converter for that like `StringToUser` converter. Furthermore you have to change `userProfiles` collection type from `Set` to `List`(Ordered Collection) in User class in order to jsp work properly.

Comment: Yes , I have another class called RoleToUserProfileConverter

Comment: public UserProfile convert(Object element) {
  Integer id = Integer.parseInt((String)element);
  UserProfile profile= userProfileService.findById(id);
  logger.info("Profile : {}",profile);
  return profile;
 }

Comment: I tested your gist code in my own. It is working fine for me.

Comment: The problem is that I have Two form , when one form works the other not (when I comment the user Converter , the user form works fine but the car form don't work , when I use user Converter the car form works fine but the user form don't work and the error is : Failed to convert value of type User to required type User ; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException

Comment: this is the user controller and form : https://gist.github.com/alaa-bourouissi/ea06d373394e247ac308ab578461788f

Comment: Debug your post data when you sending to the server. Track data by chrome developer tools (Inspect Element). And debug it on server side.

Comment: https://github.com/alaa-bourouissi/SpringMVCHibernate , Please Dariush , you can find all code here

Comment: Alaa sorry I'm on holiday